# How to send escape sequences in a string over socket communication in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, socket.io, escaping, ascii, serversocket

So for a University Project we are supposed to write a server which communicate with clients,

> Communication between server and robots is implemented via a pure textual protocol. Each command ends with a pair of special symbols "\a\b"

I was able to easily implement this in python

```
    sock.sendall("message\a\b".encode())
```

But in Kotlin, since `\a` is not a valid escape sequence, so when I do this

```
   client.getOutputStream().write("message\a\b".toByteArray())
```

I get the error that "\a" is an Illegal Escape Sequence.

To Tackle this problem I figured out that kotlin doesn't recognise the escape sequence "\a", so I used the unicode equivalent sequence "\u0007",

```
   client.getOutputStream().write("Message\u0007\b".toByteArray())
```

but still the client doesn't recognise it as the same as "\a\b", Hence the client doesn't understand the message.

Does anybody know how can I end my messages to the client socket with "\a\b" in kotlin

Here is the complete ClientHandler class

```
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.net.Socket
import java.util.Scanner

class ClientHandler(private val client: Socket) {

    private val reader: Scanner = Scanner(client.getInputStream())
    private val writer: OutputStream = client.getOutputStream()
    private var running: Boolean = false

    lateinit var username: String
    lateinit var hash: String
    lateinit var clientHash: String
    var key: Int = 0
    var direction: Int = 0
    lateinit var currenCoordinates: Coordinates
    lateinit var previousCoordinates: Coordinates
    lateinit var messageStore: String


    fun run() {
        running = true
        try {
            getUsername()
            sendKeyRequest()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            shutdown()
        } finally {
        }
    }

    private fun getUsername() {
        val username = reader.nextLine().toString()
        writer.write("Message".toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII))
        writer.flush()
        client.close()
        println(username)
    }

    private fun write(message: String) {
        writer.write("Message".toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII))
        writer.flush()
        println("Sent Message: $message")
    }

    private fun sendKeyRequest() {
        write("107 KEY REQUEST\u0007\b")
    }

    private fun shutdown() {
        running = false
        client.close()
        println("Connection was closed")
    }

    private fun calculateHash(username: String): Int {
        var sum: Int = 0

        for (char in username) {
            sum = char.code
        }
        return (sum * 1000) % 65536
    }

}

data class Coordinates(val x: Int, val y: Int)
```

Comment: By saying you need to send "\a\b" do you mean 4 bytes with backspaces and letters, or do you mean 2 bytes, so these escapes actually resolve to something? If the latter, what are byte representations of these chars?

Comment: @broot I mean 2 bytes, so these escapes are resolved to their ascii values.

Comment: So, I can see `"message\u0007\b".toByteArray()` is properly converted to `[109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 7, 8]`. This part looks good, maybe the problem is in another place? I see you inconsistently used "Message` with capital "M", but I guess that should not matter. Did you flush after writing?

Comment: Also, please be aware by default `toByteArray()` uses `UTF-8`. If you expect ASCII on the server side, then you should choose it explicitly: `toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII)`. Although, in this specific case it should not matter.

Comment: I am not sure if the problem is somewhere else, because the client tester timeout waiting for the end sequence of message from server. 

I pasted my ClientHandler class here for reference here.

Comment: To be honest, either I miss something or I don't know how this code was supposed to work ;-) In `getUsername()` you don't send these magic bytes and you already close the connection to the client. Then you write bytes in `sendKeyRequest()`, but this is after closing the socket. You most probably got `IOException` here, but your code silently ignores any exceptions in `run()`.